# socket.io and filtering mongodb by object id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

I'm trying to get a document from a mongoDB collection by object id while using Socket.io. 
As `findById()` doesn't work here and i cant do `find({ "_id" : _id})` i dont know how to proceed.

This gives me back my entire collection on the client side. But i just want one document by the given _id.

The _id arrives on the server side. I have checked.

THanks in advance

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('user arrived');
  socket.emit('chat-message', 'hello-world');
  socket.on('send-chat-id', _id => {
    console.log(_id);
    const chats = db.collection('chats');
    chats.find().toArray(function(error, result) { <------
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      socket.emit('chat-messages', result);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use `findById()` you need to convert a parameter being passed in from `string` (coming from UI) into `ObjectId` by using below line:

```
const objectId = new ObjectId(_id)
```